# Highcharts parsed drilldown not showing on page but does in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, csv, highcharts

I have set up a simple column chart in Highcharts 4 with jQuery 1.9.1 where I parse a CSV file.  I get the normal page showing with the column chart, but when I click on a bar nothing happens.  I actually do see the arrays being created in the console (IE11) and they appear to be just what I need, they are in the correct syntax and the IDs match.

The JS fiddle [was...://jsfiddle.net/tjxwty3y/ ... I have changed this in the edit at the bottom ] .  I put an example of the CSV that I use, but do not know how to link an external one into the JS Fiddle.  I have tried the examples with CSV/TSVs embedded in the code and they have worked, so I think it has to do with how I am pushing the data, hence the external reference.

The CSV is very simple.  I have the 3 categories in the first column, their values for the front chart, followed by the IDs in the 3rd and finally the drilldown values in the 4th and 5th.

```
CSV looks like this
AREA,VALUE,TYPE,SHIFT1,SHIFT2
Blog1,50000,Blog1_Shift,5,6
Blog2,60000,Blog2_Shift,2,3
Blog3,40000,Blog3_Shift,7,8
```

I have looked at multiple posts (and some videos) where the CSV or TSV is within the JS Fiddle and on Highcharts website, but I completely am not seeing where I have gone wrong (and I know that I have).

Just in case, here is the raw data from js fiddle which has the libraries (I typically use Higcharts 4 and JQuery 1.11 but here I've modified some older code that used JQuery 1.9.1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title> - jsFiddle demo</title>

    <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>
    <style type='text/css'></style>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        //<![CDATA[
        $(window).load(function () {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var options = {
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'column'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'My Title Here'
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: [],
                        name: []
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Value Here'
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {

                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        y: 15,
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        itemStyle: {

                            color: '#333',
                            fontSize: '15px',

                        },
                        navigation: {
                            activeColor: '#3E576F',
                            animation: true,
                            arrowSize: 12,
                            inactiveColor: '#CCC',

                            style: {
                                fontWeight: 'bold',
                                color: '#333',
                                fontSize: '15px',

                            }
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        shared: true,
                        crosshairs: true
                    },

                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {

                            marker: {
                                lineWidth: 1
                            }
                        }
                    },

                    series: [],
                    drilldown: []

                };

                $.get("http://my/csv/notvalid/dev_drilldown4.csv", function (csvData) {

                    var lines = csvData.split('\n');

                    var series = {
                        data: [],
                        visible: true,
                        type: 'column',
                        colorByPoint: true,
                        drilldown: true
                    };

                    var drilldown = {
                        series: []
                    };

                    $.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {

                        if (lineNo > 0 && lineNo < 4) {

                            var items = line.split(',');
                            var seriesname = String(items[0]); // this is the area
                            var area_cost = parseFloat(items[1]); // this is the data for the rollup
                            var drill_id = String(items[2]); // this will be the id of the drilldown
                            var shift_one_value = parseFloat(items[3]); // shift1 value
                            var shift_two_value = parseFloat(items[4]); // shift2 value

                            series.data.push({
                                name: seriesname,
                                y: area_cost,
                                drilldown: drill_id
                            });

                            drilldown.series.push({
                                id: drill_id,
                                data: [["shift1", shift_one_value],["shift2", shift_two_value]]
                            });

                        }


                    });
                    console.log(series.data);
                    console.log(drilldown.series);

                    options.series.push({ data: series.data });
                    options.drilldown.push({ series: drilldown.series });

                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
            });
        });

    </script>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I appreciate any for help/advice.
Thanks

EDIT:
Now that I have added in Salman's and Pawell's edits, including adding in the CSV to the jsFiddle (see Pawell's jsFiddle for what it now looks like) I encountered an additional issue, but it is/was working now!

I realized I forgot the "name" of the series and added that in, adjusting the 'var series' and changing the 'series.data.push' to 'series.push' and watched the log as mentioned by Salman.  Now nothing appears, but the console log appears to show the data with the names, ids and data, but no chart (and no error).

The js fiddle is:  http://jsfiddle.net/5jzb8hzb/1/.  Would you know why changing the 'series.data.push' caused the initial chart to not render?

Comment: Can you upload the csv file (http://my/csv/notvalid/dev_drilldown4.csv) one a web server and run the jsFiddle again?

Comment: Thanks Salman, that initially helped a lot and it did get to work.  I added in the embedded csv and innerHTML as Pawel recommended (though still trying to get that to work).  Thanks for the recommendation on viewing the options in the log, which helped me to see the difference.  I'll comment on Pawel's next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noticed by @Salman, there is a couple of issues:

- first load Highcahrts then drilldown.js (issue only in jsFiddle)
- you shouldn't push to the drilldown array, but assign created series
- you have `drilldown: []`, while should be `drilldown: {}`
- for series you have `options.series.push({ data: series.data })`, while simply use `options.series.push(series)` or `options.series = [series]`

Extra note: I suggest to check values if those are not NaN's - sometimes editors create extra empty new line at the end of the file.

After all fixes, here is fully working code: http://jsfiddle.net/tjxwty3y/7/

Minimized example:

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    series: [],
    drilldown: {}

};

var csvData = document.getElementById("data").innerHTML; // like $.get()
var lines = csvData.split('\n');

var series = {
    data: [],
    visible: true,
    type: 'column',
    colorByPoint: true,
    drilldown: true
};

var drilldown = {
    series: []
};
// I know with the below I get an extra line so can deal with that when I get the rest of the data sorted

$.each(lines, function (lineNo, line) {

    if (lineNo > 0 && lineNo < 4) {

        var items = line.split(',');
        var seriesname = String(items[0]); // this is the area name
        var area_cost = parseFloat(items[1]); // this is the data for the area rollup
        var drill_id = String(items[2]); // this will be the id of the drilldown
        var shift_one_value = parseFloat(items[3]); // drilldown shift1 value
        var shift_two_value = parseFloat(items[4]); // drilldown shift2 value

        if(!isNaN(area_cost) && !isNaN(shift_one_value) && !isNaN(shift_two_value))  {
            series.data.push({
                name: seriesname,
                y: area_cost,
                drilldown: drill_id
            });
            drilldown.series.push({
                id: drill_id,
                data: [
                    ["shift1", shift_one_value],
                    ["shift2", shift_two_value]
                ]
            });
        }
    }
});
options.series = [series];
options.drilldown = drilldown;

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

Comment: Thanks Pawel.  That cleared up the "=" vs "push" a bit more (I'll read more on that).  With yours and Salmon's the drilldown worked.  I also appreciate you showing how to embed the CSV and use innerHTML.  One thing I am missing though is that I don't have the drilldown names.  I used a version of yours, and Salman's suggestion of checking the options log, but I'm getting nothing now.  I'm not sure if this is the correct etiquette to add that in, but will do so and can remove it.  This merely changes the series.data.push to series.push to add the series name.

Comment: It depends what exactly is your name? See example: http://jsfiddle.net/tjxwty3y/13/

Comment: Actually, it was how to have a general name as opposed to "series 2" for example.  The code you have makes it clear.  It is also clear I have not understood the API syntax for moving data from a function to options to the chart.  My goal will be a multi-column drilldown, hence wanting the series name, but I think I can work that out based on the updates youput in.  Thanks a lot Pawel!

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the code; if you log `options` you will detect it. `drilldown` configuration is supposed to have a `series` key. But in your case the key is inside `drilldown[0]`; probably because of using `push` function.

The code worked after I changed

```
options.drilldown.push({ series: drilldown.series });
```

to

```
options.drilldown.series = drilldown.series;
```

There was also another bug- drilldown library should be loaded *after* highcharts.

**Edit:** Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dxann41x/1/